# Replace Standard C++ Allocator?

Tags: c++, allocator

I want to replace the standard allocator with a more robust allocator (the C++ standard only requires an overflow check on vector::resize). The various C++ allocators supplied with many libraries fall flat on their face when fed negative self tests.

I have access to a more robust allocator. ESAPI's allocator not only checks for overflow, it also has debug instrumentation to help find mistakes. http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-cplusplus/source/browse/trunk/esapi/util/zAllocator.h.

Is there a standard way to replace the C++ allocator used in a program without too much effort? I also want to ensure its replaced in library code, which I may not have access to source code.

Comment: AFAIK, all of the standard container constructors take an optional allocator.

Comment: Yes. How do I replace it across the board without visiting every declaration in every source file?

Comment: I'm sure there's some regex that would do it pretty easily if the declarations are consistent. Even if not, you can account for specific inconsistencies.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a "SetNewAndDelete" or something similar....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike `malloc` which is a library function that can be replaced by another function with the same signature, `std::allocator` is a class template and template code is instantiated as needed and inlined into code that uses it.  Some standard library code will have already been compiled into the library's object files and will contain instantiated `std::allocator`  code which can't be replaced.  So the only way is if the standard library provides some non-standard way to replace its `std::allocator`.  Luckily, GCC's libstdc++ allows you to do just that, allowing you to select the implementation used for `std::allocator` when GCC is configured and built, with a few [different choices](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/memory.html#allocator.ext)

It wouldn't be too much work to add the ESAPI allocator to the GCC sources as one of the options, then rebuild GCC to use that allocator as the base class of `std::allocator` providing its implementation.  You might need to tweak the ESAPI allocator code a bit, and maybe alter the libstdc++ `configure` script to allow you to say `--enable-libstdcxx-allocator=esapi`

Comment: Cool, thanks Jonathan. "You might need to tweak the ESAPI allocator code a bit" - considering how much you have helped us, I would not be surprised if no tweaking was required.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to modify allocation on a global basis instead of per-container, you probably want to replace `::operator new` and `::operator delete`. Conceivably, you'd also want to replace `::operator new[]` and `::operator delete[]` as well -- but these are only used for allocating arrays, which you should almost never use anyway (aside, in case it wasn't obvious: no, these are *not* used to allocate memory for a `std::vector`, despite its being rather similar to an array in some ways).

Although trying to replace most parts of the library is prohibited, the standard specifically allows replacing these.

Of course, if somebody is already specifying a different allocator for a particular container, and that allocator doesn't (eventually) get its memory via `::operator new` (or `::operator new[]`) this will *not* affect that container/those containers.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I don't think there is an easy way to do this for something simple like an allocator. I know there's no way to easily handle all the different element insertion points. I'm ready to ban STL code from the code bases under my control (I wish there was a security minded alternative).

Comment: Note for the later reference, [here is how to replace the operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). Seems pretty simple if there's no extra caveats…

Answer (score 4):

In C++0x, define a new template alias in namespace `mystd` that is a `std::vector` but with your custom allocator.  Replace all `std::vector`s with `mystd::vector`.  Get rid of all `using namespace std` and `using std::vector` in your code.

Rebuild.  Replace the places where you used a raw `vector<T>` with `mystd::vector<T>`.

Oh, and use a better name than `mystd`.

Comment: Is the std::allocator weakly linked? Can I perform an end around by offering a strongly linked symbol?

Comment: It's a template, not a symbol that can be linked.